# Fetch Specific Columns in table with specific column in relationship table in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-query-builder

Here I have two model. User and Company.

Inside User model:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
}
```

Inside Company model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And when I fetch users using query below:

```
User::query()
        ->with(array('company' => function($company) {
            return $company->select('id', 'company_name');
        }))->get()->map->only([
            'id', 'email', 'has_employees', 'created', 'status', 'last_login_ago_day', 'company_name'
        ]);
```

This code returns only specific column of User model. I want to return also the specific column of Company model. How should I do that?

Comment: The `only` method returns only the specified keys, since you didn't specify `company_name`, it won't return it

Comment: I added company_name to my return statement but all company name got null values

Comment: You need to add `company` to your only() method. it will be a nested object with all the company fields

Comment: Yeah it's correct if you also add a foreign key id inside a company function

Answer (score 0):

Need to add foreign key id inside company closure function and in this case the `user_id`

```
User::query()->role('admin')->with(['company' => function($company) {
        $company->select('user_id', 'company_name');
    }])->get()
        ->map->only([
            'id', 'email', 'has_employees', 'created', 'status', 'last_login_ago_day', 'company'
        ]);
```